# Comic about a western that turns into a sci-fi about a crashed ship and a "Mother" AI

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I once read a short online comic, I think off the artists blog? It opens as a western. A town is trying to kill an outlaw (I think) but nothings working, not drowning, not fire, not guns.

The outlaw escapes, naturally, taking somebody with him. Then we see him in a crashed ship, sand everywhere, obviously been here a long time.

He talks with the AI of the ship, a "mother" model. He tells her he brought her one, and she thanked him, saying something to the effect of "All the children must be brought home." It's implied that the humans on this planet came on a starship that crashed, and so much time and so many generations have passed they forgot their spacefaring roots.

Comment: Welcome to the community!  There's a [list of points](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) you should check out that might help you add details to your question.  In particular, do you remember how many years ago you read this?

Comment: Early 2000's. Maybe 2004? When I was in high school, I think. (I'm in college now.) The blog was a kinda light green/sea-foam thing. Was probably on tumblr or linked through tumblr. The art style was kinda cartoony, while maintaining a pretty realistic high/leg ratio. The AI was presented as a hologram of a matronly woman, I think she was tinted green?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking of [Sand](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/story/sand), by Penny Arcade ([Full imgur gallery for quick skimming)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYQJB.jpg).

It matches your desciption exactly, so I'll just include the first page to illustrate this.

*It opens as a western. A town is trying to kill an outlaw (I think) but nothings working, not drowning, not fire, not guns.*

[image: *It opens as a western. A town is trying to kill an outlaw (I think) but nothings working, not drowning, not fire, not guns.*]